# How to distinguish multiple Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient() return

Tags: titanium

I send multiple Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient() in for loop.

When I handle the return text, I can't understand which response is correspond to each send().

How can I distinguish multiple createHTTPClient() return object??

```
url[0] = http://api.yahoo.com?key=0
url[1] = http://api.yahoo.com?key=1
url[2] = http://api.yahoo.com?key=2

var xhrArray = new Array();

for (var k = 0 ; k < 3;k++){
    var v = encodeURIComponent(url[k]);
    xhrArray[k] = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhrArray[k].autoEncodeUrl = false;
    xhrArray[k].onload = function(e){

        var response = JSON.parse(xhrArray[k].responseText);            
         //It doesnt work, How can I distinguish multiple xhr return??

    };
    xhrArray[k].open('GET', url[k], true);
    xhrArray[k].send();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign custom property to HTTPClient instance

```
xhrArray[k].myProperty = 'Hello';
```

Catch it from `this` ex:`this.myProperty`

Full example:

```
var url = [
        'http://api.yahoo.com?key=0',
        'http://api.yahoo.com?key=1',
        'http://api.yahoo.com?key=2'
    ],
    xhrArray = [];

for (var k = 0; k < 3; k++) {

    //var v = encodeURIComponent(url[k]);
    xhrArray[k] = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhrArray[k].autoEncodeUrl = false;

    // Assign your custom property
    xhrArray[k].myProperty = k;
    xhrArray[k].onerror = function(e) {

        var response = JSON.parse(xhrArray[this.myProperty].responseText);

    };
    xhrArray[k].open('GET', url[k], true);
    xhrArray[k].send();
}
```